# Why .call on String.methods works nowhere except in Firefox

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

I'm wondering on a try to convert all lower case items in an Array into upper case.
I was evaluating some variants and checked the performance where the `.call()`variant was the fastest one (http://jsperf.com/uppercaseperformance)

Used the following code which is working well in Firefox (32.0.1):

```
console.log(String.toUpperCase.call(null,['a', 'lower', 'case', 'string', 'array']))
```

**Outputs in Firefox only:**

```
A,LOWER,CASE,STRING,ARRAY <- Thats nice ;)
```

Same code isn't working in Chrome, Safari, node.js etc. 
Chrome/Safari outputs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

And node.js outputs:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

Is .call used in a wrong context here maybe?
The Browser Compatibility on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) website shows `.call()`should be supported.

Comment: `.call` is redundant here, since `String.toUpperCase` does not use the `this` object. You should use: `String.toUpperCase(['a', 'lower', 'case', 'string', 'array'])` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [String generic methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods) are not part of the ECMAScript standard, they're only shipped in Firefox.

You can shim it for all other browsers (copied directly from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods)):

```
/*globals define*/
// Assumes all supplied String instance methods already present
// (one may use shims for these if not available)
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var i,
        // We could also build the array of methods with the following, but the
        //   getOwnPropertyNames() method is non-shimable:
        // Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String).filter(function (methodName)
        //  {return typeof String[methodName] === 'function'});
        methods = [
            'quote', 'substring', 'toLowerCase', 'toUpperCase', 'charAt',
            'charCodeAt', 'indexOf', 'lastIndexOf', 'startsWith', 'endsWith',
            'trim', 'trimLeft', 'trimRight', 'toLocaleLowerCase',
            'toLocaleUpperCase', 'localeCompare', 'match', 'search',
            'replace', 'split', 'substr', 'concat', 'slice'
        ],
        methodCount = methods.length,
        assignStringGeneric = function (methodName) {
            var method = String.prototype[methodName];
            String[methodName] = function (arg1) {
                return method.apply(arg1, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            };
        };

    for (i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {
        assignStringGeneric(methods[i]);
    }
}());
```

---

Note that using the shim above just adds some abstraction on top of this:

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase.apply(['a', 'lower', 'case', 'string', 'array']);
// "A,LOWER,CASE,STRING,ARRAY"
```

The interesting part here is that an array is being used as the `this` value for a String method.

According to the spec ([§ 15.5.4.18](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.18) -> [§ 15.5.4.16](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.16) step 2), the `this` binding is coerced to a string through the internal [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8) algorithm, which for objects (note that arrays are objects) invokes the internal [ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) algorithm, which in turn calls the array's [`toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2) method, which in turn calls the array's [`join`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.5) method with an empty arguments list.

That is, calling `.toUpperCase()` passing an array as the `this` binding will first implicitly coerce `this` to a string:

```
['a', 'b'].toString() === ['a', 'b'].join();
['a', 'b'].join() === 'a,b';
```

Then `toUpperCase` will map this string's characters to their equivalent uppercase characters. Therefore:

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase.apply(['a', 'b']) === ['a', 'b'].join().toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Cheers for finding that link on the generic methods, was Googling my ass off for that one   :)

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a peculiarity in Firefox, more of a hidden feature than a bug though.

`toUpperCase` is actually, by the standards, only available as a [prototype method of `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase), and as such should be invoked on a valid instance. You could of course try:

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase.call(null,['a', 'lower', 'case', 'string', 'array'])
```

Which, in Chrome, obviously returns:

```
TypeError: String.prototype.toUpperCase called on null or undefined
```

As invoking `call(null, ...)` on it will invoke the instance method with an empty `this` reference. The static invocation style you are attempting [is only implemented in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods) and not part of any current ECMAScript standard.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. OP wants to use the `String.toUpperCase` function (which seems to be supported only on Firefox), not the `String.prototype.toUpperCase` function. The asker's code could be simplified to omit the `.call`.

Comment: @FengyangWang I wrote the answer not knowing about the String Generic methods in Firefox. As they're not part of any ECMAScript standard and just a curious Firefox-only invention, I assumed he was mistaking the prototype's possible uses. Doesn't make the answer in itself wrong.

Comment: Yes, your answer is very well written, but I believe you should address the generic ("static") `String.toUpperCase` method instead of the prototype one -- that's why I submitted an answer as well. `;)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté as you should, I upvoted yours as it's a more directly correct answer for the Firefox part. I consider both our answers to fully answer the 'underlying issue'.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: Okay, but your code does not work on any browser right now (the `null` must be removed, since it's the array that should be the `this` object). Otherwise the answer is well-written.

Comment: Yep, as @FengyangWang said, you should pass the array as the `this` value (as done in [ronnyfm's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25923086/1331430)). The array will be coerced to a string, which will be the string representation of its items joined by a comma.

Comment: Passing an array as the `this` binding for a string method is rather amusing though. I've expanded on this on my answer in case anyone's curious. `;)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté but actually [that is intentional by spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-string.prototype.touppercase)  :)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes yep, I've covered my explanation with links to the current ES spec. `=]` JavaScript's implicit type coercion may be a simple concept for us, but it can be mind-blowing for starters. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `String.prototype.toUpperCase.call(['a', 'lower', 'case', 'string', 'array'])`

Comment: Tested Firefox and Safari. You only need to specify one parameter.